# Would it be possible to build faceted search with django-filters and Postgres Full-Text Search?

Tags: django, postgresql, elasticsearch, django-forms, django-filter

I want to build faceted search with django-filters and Postgres Full-Text Search. But I didn't find anywhere how to do it. May it be impossible. I noticed that people build faceted search with elastic. But I don't know it will be works with django-filters, or I will need to build without it.
It needs me for search and filters books/
Can you give me any advice how to do it?